# How can I get the src of a video a safe it into a variable?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to find a way to get the source code of a video from a page and safe it into a variable in JavaScript. I already tried many ways, but every time I get "undefined" back.

```
<video width="800" height="450" style="width: 100%;" class="video" data-ended="/lernen/00/done" 
src="/media/video/99.webm">
<source type="video/mp4" src="/media/video/99.mp4">
</object>
</video>
```

I tried this, and thought that would look for the source within the class and store it in the variable. I just started using JavaScript today,

```
var src = document.getElementsByClassName("video").src
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an array like object, which will not have a `src` property.  You would need to get the `[0].src` perhaps

Comment: thank u a lot! Another question: do src return a string?

Answer (score 3):

If you use class and `getElementsByClassName()` method it returns list of result so, you  need to take the first one.

If you  use id and `getElementById()` method then it returns just one element then you take take it directly.

If you use `querySelector()` method it returns first element then you  can take it directly.

If you use `querySelectorAll()` method it returns list of elements matched, then you can take first element of list.

clas with first element or queryselector(it returns always first one)

```js
src = document.getElementsByClassName("video")[0].src;
console.log(src);
 src = document.getElementById("video").src;
console.log(src);
src = document.querySelector(".video").src;
console.log(src)
src = document.querySelectorAll(".video")[0].src;
console.log(src)
```

```html
<video width="800" height="450"id="video" style="width: 100%;" class="video" data-ended="/lernen/00/done" 
src="/media/video/99.webm">
<source type="video/mp4" src="/media/video/99.mp4">
</object>
</video>
```

Answer (score 2):

> The [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) method of Document interface returns
>   an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given
>   class name(s).

So you have to use one of the elements from the array, first `[0]` for example:

```js
var src = document.getElementsByClassName("video")[0].src
console.log(src)
```

```html
<video width="800" height="450" style="width: 100%;" class="video" data-ended="/lernen/00/done" src="/media/video/99.webm">
<source type="video/mp4" src="/media/video/99.mp4">
</object>
</video>
```